# What can you learn about someone's mother and father by examining their DNA?

Tags: genetics, dna, dna-sequencing

Disclaimer: I ask this question from the position of having paid absolutely no attention throughout school/highschool science classes. I am incredibly ignorant, but I don't know how to find the answer to this question using google, and would rather consult actual live minds via this stackexchange.

My question is (I think) fairly straightforward: By examining someone's DNA, how much can you learn about their mother and father? Is it perhaps possible to analyse the DNA and do the equivalent of a "fast fourier transform" to extract and reconstruct the respective DNAs of their mother and father?

Comment: I have found that when learning about a new area starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/science/biology/) is very helpful. Wikipedia is also generally a good starting point and you can then check their references. Online platforms called MOOCs offer free (or very low cost) courses on a wide variety of subjects — two I am familiar with are [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [edX](http://edx.org). Finally, textbooks with a good level of detail are also freely available online e.g. from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/).

Answer (score 1):

In principle, you can reconstruct 1/2 the genome of each parent.

Each of these halves is still a "complete" genome, in the sense that it (usually) contains 23 full chromosomes (there are 23 human chromosomes). Every person has two copies of their genome, one of which is inherited from each parent. I strongly recommend reading about [meiosis](https://www.yourgenome.org/facts/what-is-meiosis#:%7E:text=Meiosis%20is%20a%20process%20where,to%20form%20four%20daughter%20cells.) to learn more about this.

Each of these single genome copies is called a [haplotype](https://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/haplotype-haplotypes-142#:%7E:text=A%20haplotype%20is%20a%20group,genetic%20makeup%20of%20an%20organism.), and is an outcome of [recombination](https://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/genetic-recombination-514) between their own two genome copies. So neither copy looks exactly like a parent, but is rather a mixed-up version of that parent's genome.

There are a lot of genomic methods out there that try do exactly this task (reconstructing parental haplotypes) by various means. It is somewhat complicated and expensive, but possible in principle:

- One method is [trio-binning](https://www.nature.com/articles/nbt.4277), which involves also collecting data from the parents, but focusing most effort on the child. This is not very convenient of course if you don't have samples from the parents.
- Other methods use only information from the child, but rely on various genome technologies to reconstruct haplotypes inherited from each parent. [Here is an early example](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/327064v1), and [here is a very recent example](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41587-020-0711-0). These methods however do this mostly on a chromosome-by-chromosome basis, so it is not always obvious how to group the 46 total chromosomes into 2 parental haplotypes of 23 each.

This is a very active area of methods development, so we can expect these references to be quickly outdated.

I do not think that any method will be able to use only the DNA of the child to reconstruct the full genomes of the parents. Maybe if you have a large database of other genomes you can do some imputation of the missing haplotypes, but I doubt that that would work very well.